# Building Blackberry Playbook App in Adobe AIR/FLEX

Tags: apache-flex, blackberry, adobe

Ive been trying to write my first Blackberry Adobe Flex application but get the following errors:

`1172: Definition mx.controls:Label could not be found.`

Any idea why?

Thanks
Phil

Comment: (Sigh...) Any context? (where, what program, what SDK...)

Comment: You leave a lot to the imagination here.  It's like saying "I can't find my cellphone, any idea why?". A little bit more would be great...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't include the MX namespace: xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"

But don't use mx.controls:Label try the spark label (s:Label) (include the xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark")